# Is Perron method practically possible to implement?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was reading Perron method. I understand this method . But as it involves fining all sub function related to boundary data. Which I think may not possible to find .

So I think this method only theoretical . We can not use to apply this practically. Is this true? If not please give me reference to find problem.

Any help will be appreciated